# How to Traverse between children in JavaScript to create breadcrumb UI from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

What I need is to create a breadcrumb from a JSON defining the structure of the breadcrumb.

> Parent / Node >Comm> Forms Code>Test  Menu

Problem

[image: >A>B>Comm>comm Code>Forms Code>Test Menu]

In Nested Json object parent_id is related to id in json object.

Js code

```
        ngOnInit() {
            let data = [];
            let jsonValues = JSON.stringify(this.jasonData1);
            const main_menu_items = JSON.parse(jsonValues);

            var treeNodes = [];

            this.childernNodes = nestedChildrens(main_menu_items.value, 0);

            console.log(this.childernNodes);

            function nestedChildrens(nodes, level) {
              //treeNodes[level] = treeNodes[level] || [];
              var total = 0;

              nodes.children.forEach(node => {
                var ccount = 0;

                if ("children" in node) {
                  var ccount = nestedChildrens(node, total + 1);
                } else {
                  ccount = 1;
                }
                // console.log(node.parent_id);

                treeNodes.push({
                  node,
                  tree_node: total
                });

                total += ccount;
              });

              const sorted = Object.values(treeNodes).sort(
                (a, b) => a.node.id - b.node.id
              );
              return sorted;
            }
          }
        }
```

Stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tree-node-test-znreuv

Any suggestion is most welcome

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to make breadcrumbs recursive   from Nested Json objects where   children parent_id has relation with id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary of nodes indexed by id, then starting at the leaf node follow the parent_id's and get the parent nodes from the dictionary you created in the beginning. As you go, append the nodes to the beginning of an array representing the breadcrumb.

Something like:

While traversing:

```
    nodesDictionary[node.id] = {
      node,
      tree_node: total
    };
```

Then:

```
let currentNode = nodesDictionary["156"];
while (currentNode && currentNode.node.parent_id) {
  this.childernNodes = [currentNode, ...this.childernNodes];
  currentNode = nodesDictionary[currentNode.node.parent_id];
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tree-node-test-hphtlw?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for the help.. Please can you help & i need this output Parent / Node >Comm> Forms Code>Test Menu

Comment: @afeef the "Parent / Node" does not exist in your nodes... you can either add it to the collection or statically in the component Markup.
I'm adding it in the component markup in the linked stackblitz and also changing the separators to ">" instead of "/". check the tree.component.css and tree.component.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply jasonData1 = {
    key: "1",
    value: {
      id: "150",
      code: "p",
      name: "Parent / Node",
      parent_id: null,
      url: "parent-url",

      children: [
        {          This is already as root element in json Object

Comment: you are right :) fixed it to use the root node as well